# Raw Image data format from iOS Camera

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, core-image

I need to save raw data from the iOS camera to the cloud. I get a `CVPixelBuffer` from the iOS camera. I do not specify what format (`kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey`) I want the `CVPixelBuffer` in when I set up the iOS camera.

I turn the `CVPixelBuffer` into a `Data` object like this.

```swift
let buffer: CVPixelBuffer = //My buffer from the camera

//Get the height for the size calculation
let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(buffer)

//Get the bytes per row for the size calculation
let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(buffer)

//Lock the buffer so we can turn it into data
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(buffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags.readOnly)

//Get the base address. This is the address in memory of where the start of the buffer is currently stored.
guard let pointer = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(buffer) else {
    //If we failed to get the base address unlock the buffer and clean up.
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(buffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags.readOnly)
    return
}

let data = Data(bytes: pointer, count: height * bytesPerRow)
```

Am I doing this right?

Also, when I get this data back how would I turn it into a `CIImage`?

Comment: I'm not sure why are you asking the last question `Also, when I get this data back how would I turn it into a CIImage?` when you're already dealing with such advanced Core Video framework. But when you get correct data (`Data`), you can use such object to create a `CIImage` object by `CIImage(data: )`.

Comment: Something to look at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/capturing_still_and_live_photos/capturing_photos_in_raw_format